# How to check if a textbox contains at least one digit in VB

Tags: vb.net, validation

I am using this code

```
If Not s.Contains("1") Or s.Contains("0") Or s.Contains("2") Or _
       s.Contains("3") Or s.Contains("4") Or s.Contains("5") Or _
       s.Contains("6") Or s.Contains("7") Or s.Contains("8") Or s.Contains("9") Then
            MsgBox("Password must contain one digit")
End If
```

But when I enter more than one digit, it does not work.
For e.g. `abc1234`, it shows the message `"Password must contain one digit"`, but if I write `abc1`, it works.

Comment: Not should be with every s.Contains or Not (s.Contains(0) or s.contains(1)....)

Comment: wat are you trying to say

Comment: If Not (s.Contains("1") Or s.Contains("0") Or s.Contains("2") Or s.Contains("3") Or s.Contains("4") Or s.Contains("5") Or s.Contains("6") Or s.Contains("7") Or s.Contains("8") Or s.Contains("9")) Then MsgBox("Password must contain one digit") End If

Comment: Thanx got it .if Not (s.Contains("1") Or s.Contains("0") Or s.Contains("2") Or s.Contains("3") Or s.Contains("4") Or s.Contains("5") Or s.Contains("6") Or s.Contains("7") Or s.Contains("8") Or s.Contains("9"))

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to a regex solution, you can use `Char.IsDigit` to check if a character is a digit or not.

```
Dim str = "pass1234"
Dim hasDigit = str.ToCharArray().Any(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'd just use a regex here.

```
Dim re As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d")
If Not re.IsMatch(s) Then
    MsgBox("Password must contain at least one digit")
End If
```

And you're done! (`\d` is the short form for "any single digit".)

Answer (score 1):

You must use `AndAlso Not` on each for your code to work...

```
If Not s.Contains("1") AndAlso Not s.Contains("0") AndAlso Not s.Contains("2") AndAlso Not _
   s.Contains("3") AndAlso Not s.Contains("4") AndAlso Not s.Contains("5") AndAlso Not _
   s.Contains("6") AndAlso Not s.Contains("7") AndAlso Not s.Contains("8") AndAlso Not s.Contains("9") Then
        MsgBox("Password must contain one digit")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of good answers but I just wanted to expand a little on what you tied.
You were missing an extra set of (). You needed to "Not" the whole if statement.

```
If Not ( s.Contains("1") Or s.Contains("0") Or s.Contains("2") Or _
       s.Contains("3") Or s.Contains("4") Or s.Contains("5") Or _
       s.Contains("6") Or s.Contains("7") Or s.Contains("8") Or s.Contains("9") ) Then
            MsgBox("Password must contain one digit")
End If
```